# TranscationScope with multiple database calls

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactionscope

My scenario is to send invoice details (in PDF format) to customer's emailId on paynow button click event.

I have tried the following but getting exception after calling

```
actionPDF.BuildPdf(ControllerContext)
```

Exception is

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Code:

```
dbDetails _db = new dbDetails();

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Add(Model mdl)
{
    using (TransactionScope _ts = new TransactionScope())
    {
        //Insertion logic of invoice goes here
        ...
        ...

        int i = _db.SaveChanges();

        // if successfull insertion
        if(i > 0)
        {
            var actionPDF = new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("GetPdfReceipt", new { RegId = _receiptDetails.StudentRegistrationID.Value })
            {
               FileName = "Receipt.pdf"
            };

            // Dynamic student receipt pdf
            ***Getting exception here****
            var byteArrayDynamic = actionPDF.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);

            // Mail sending logic
            ......
            ......

            _ts.Complete();   
        }
    }
} 

public ActionResult GetPdfReceipt(int RegId)
{
     Common _cmn = new Common();
     var _studentRegistration = _db.StudentRegistrations
                                 .AsEnumerable()
                                 .Where(r => r.Id == RegId)
                                 .FirstOrDefault();

    var _mdlReceiptPdf = new ReceiptPdfVM
    {
         CentreCode = _studentRegistration.StudentWalkInn.CenterCode.CentreCode,
         CompanyAddress = _studentRegistration.StudentWalkInn.CenterCode.Address,
         CompanyPhoneNo = _studentRegistration.StudentWalkInn.CenterCode.PhoneNo,
         CourseFee = _studentRegistration.TotalCourseFee.Value,
         CourseTitle = string.Join(",", _studentRegistration.StudentRegistrationCourses
                                              .Select(rc => rc.MultiCourse.CourseSubTitle.Name)),
         CROName = _studentRegistration.StudentWalkInn.CROCount == (int)EnumClass.CROCount.ONE ? _studentRegistration.StudentWalkInn.Employee1.Name :
                                                                                                  _studentRegistration.StudentWalkInn.Employee1.Name + ',' + _studentRegistration.StudentWalkInn.Employee2.Name,
         Duration = _studentRegistration.TotalDuration.Value,
         ReceiptDate = _studentRegistration.StudentReceipts.Last(sr => sr.Status == true).DueDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
         ReceiptNo = _studentRegistration.StudentReceipts.Last(sr => sr.Status == true).ReceiptNo,
         RegistrationNumber = _studentRegistration.RegistrationNumber,
         ServiceTax = _studentRegistration.TotalSTAmount.Value,
         StudentMaskedEmailId = _cmn.MaskString(_studentRegistration.StudentWalkInn.EmailId, "email"),
         StudentMaskedMobileNo = _cmn.MaskString(_studentRegistration.StudentWalkInn.MobileNo, "mobile"),
         StudentName = _studentRegistration.StudentWalkInn.CandidateName,
         ServiceTaxRegistrationNo = _studentRegistration.StudentWalkInn.CenterCode.STRegNo,
         TotalAmount = _studentRegistration.TotalAmount.Value,
         TotalAmountInWords = _cmn.NumbersToWords(_studentRegistration.TotalAmount.Value).ToUpper(),
         TotalCourseFeePaid = _studentRegistration.StudentReceipts
                                   .Where(r => r.Status == true)
                                   .Sum(r => r.Fee.Value),
         ManagerName = _cmn.GetManager(_studentRegistration.StudentWalkInn.CenterCodeId.Value)
                              .Name,
         ReceiptDetailsList = _db.StudentReceipts
                                       .AsEnumerable()
                                       .Where(rc => rc.StudentRegistrationID == RegId)
                                       .Select(rc => new ReceiptPdfVM.ReceiptDetails
                                       {
                                           CourseFee = rc.Fee.Value,
                                           DatePaid = rc.DueDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                                           ReceiptNo = rc.ReceiptNo
                                       }).ToList()
    }

    return View("Receipts", _mdlReceiptPdf);
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
        _db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

How to solve this issue? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you do any more database operations after `_db.SaveChanges()`?

Comment: Yes, select operations are performed for loading the `View - Receipts` mentioned in `GetPdfReceipt()`

Comment: The select statements do not have to participate in a transaction. If all data manipulations are complete, you can finish the transaction and then perform the selects.

Comment: Updated the question with selected details.Pls check it.

Comment: Did you try this without the TransactionScope? Does the pdf build correctly? Maybe a stacktrace could help to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that while generating the PDF document your pending database transaction times out. Move the `_ts.Complete` to before you generate the PDF.

```
dbDetails _db = new dbDetails();

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Add(Model mdl)
{
    using (TransactionScope _ts = new TransactionScope())
    {
        //Insertion logic of invoice goes here
        ...
        ...
        int i= _db.SaveChanges();
        //if successfull insertion
        if(i>0)
        {
            _ts.Complete();  
            var actionPDF = new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("GetPdfReceipt", new { RegId = _receiptDetails.StudentRegistrationID.Value })
            {
               FileName = "Receipt.pdf"
            };
            //Dynamic student receipt pdf
            ***Getting exception here****
            var byteArrayDynamic = actionPDF.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);

           //Mail sending logic
           ......
           ......



        }


    }

}
```

Comment: The only logical reason I can see now is that one of the queries takes a long time to complete, therefore timing out your connection.